# iPhone Go button Does not apper if textarea is the last input

Tags: iphone, submit, forms

I have this weird issue with a form on one of my sites. Form have 2 input fields a text input and a textarea under it. Submit button at the bottom and it is inout type sumit.

When I type in text input "GO" button appears on the keyboard, but, when typing in textarea it turns to "return" button.

If i change location of inputs so that text input is the last Go button appears as usually. as I fill text are first.

Is it possible to get Go button appear while typing in textarea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your laptop or desktop and click a textarea. Pressing the enter button does not submit the form.

The answer to your question is therefore simple: a textarea is a multiline input field which requires a return button, leaving no space for the go button. The answer is no. Use a normal input instead.

Comment: Thanks, I can't use normal input. It must be text area as user will input multiline string.

Comment: You cannot have two buttons and you want multiline which requires a return button. You see the problem, right? :-)

Comment: Yes I understood you but wasn;t able to accept your answer due to time limit :)